# Using a dbt metric to determine the first value of aggregated data

Tags: sql, metrics, dbt, dbt-metrics

I am trying to incorporate dbt metrics in my data model which contains information about my customer base over various dimensions and over time. I want to create a metric that calculates the customer base on the earliest date of the time grain the user selects. For instance, if the user chooses to to aggregate the data per week, this metric should show the customer base on the first day of each week. The tricky part is that the metric needs to sum across the non-time dimensions while only considering the first day of the time period.

I have tried doing this by filtering on the date_day being min(date_day), but this does not work:

```
  - name: customer_base_on_first_day
    label: Customer Base On First Day
    model: ref('msp_churn_metric')
    calculation_method: sum
    expression: customer_base
    timestamp: date_day
    dimensions:
      - date_day
      - proposition_reference
      - has_energy_contract
      - charge_card_age
    filters:
      - field: date_day
        operator: 'is'
        value: 'min(date_day)'
```

This isn't working, because the compiled code then has an aggregated function (min) nested in an aggregated function (sum).

Does anyone know a way I can work around this?